# getting dll library functions in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a DLL library, but I am not familiar with it. How can I get its usage in vb.net?

Comment: do you want to have a glance at objects and methods? just use reflector on the dll --> http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to get a quick initial glance at what a library exposes is to create a dummy project, add a reference to the DLL and then use the Class explorer to examine the exposed pieces.

Comment: could you please let me know how to use class explorer to examine the exposed pieced of dll library

Answer (score 0):

To add to BBlake's answer; to bring up the Class View in Visual Studio 2008, just go to View -> Class View.  You can also use the Object Browser, click View -> Object Browser.